# Resolve Perl error: "Use of uninitialized value"

Tags: regex, perl

To clarify the following post, we have an automation requirement to send shipping information to an online platform so users can track their orders. We receive a daily .csv file through email, we have to extract the unique Shopify order reference from a field (last 10 digits of a field), save the amended .csv file and upload to an FTP site so tracking references can be matched to the specific order.

A previous colleague wrote an application in Perl to handle this, however it has not worked and I have no experience with Perl at all!

The program is called by a "Watcher" monitoring for files, the code for this is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Datatools::Watcher;

my $hotfolder = '\\gen-svr-01\users\DATA\MW\DMO_Report_IO\INPUT';
my $process   = '"C:\Workspace\bin\WS_DMO_Report_Manipulation_v1.0.pl"';
my @backup    = ('\\gen-svr-01\users\DATA\MW\DMO_Report_IO\ARCHIVE');

watcher($hotfolder,$process,\@backup);
```

The main code (PERL PROGRAM) is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;
use Datatools::Watcher;


my $output = '\\gen-svr-01\users\DATA\MW\DMO_Report_IO\OUTPUT';
my $desthotfolder = '\\gen-svr-01\users\DATA\MW\Data_TO_MWS_FTP_TEST';


my $shopifyPos    = 0;            
my $shopifyNew    = "";
my $header        = 1;                  


my $inputfile = $ARGV[0];    
my ($path,$file,$extention) = $inputfile =~ m/ \A (.+\/) (.+\d\d\d\d) .+ ([.]\w{3}) \z/ixms;

my $outputfilename = $file . "_FORMATTED" . $extention;
$outputfilename =~ s/.~#~//;
my $outputfile = "$output\\$outputfilename";


open (INPUT, $inputfile) or die "Could not open input file: $inputfile\n";
open (OUTPUT, ">$outputfile") or die "Could not open output file: $outputfile\n";

while (my $record = <INPUT>){
chomp $record;
my @field = parse_csv($record);
  if ($header == 1){
            print OUTPUT $record . "\n";
            $header = 0;
            next;
        } else {
            $shopifyNew = substr $field[$shopifyPos], -10;
            splice (@field, 0, 1, $shopifyNew);
            print OUTPUT join(',',@field) . "\n";
            next;
            }
    }

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;


my $destfile = "$desthotfolder\\$outputfilename";

move $outputfile, $destfile or die "Could not move output file: $outputfile\nto: $destfile\n";

print "\nProcessing complete\n";


sub parse_csv {
my ($shift) = @_;
my $text = $shift;      # record containing comma-separated values
my @new  = ();

push(@new, $+) while $text =~ m{
    # the first part groups the phrase inside the quotes.
    # see explanation of this pattern in MRE
    "([^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*)",?
       |  ([^,]+),?
       | ,
   }gx;
   push(@new, undef) if substr($text, -1,1) eq ',';
   return @new;      # list of values that were comma-separated
}
```

When the program runs, the "Watcher" details the following:

> File Seen, Processing File \\gen-svr-01\users\DATA\MW\DMO_Report_IO\INPUT/OrderTracking.csvUse of uninitialized value $file in concatenation <.>  or string at C:\Workspace\bin\WS_DMO_Report_Manipulation_v1.0.pl line 47.
>   Use of uninitialized value $extention in concatenation <.>  or string at C:\Workspace\bin\WS_DMO_Report_Manipulation_v1.0.pl line 47.
>
> Processing complete

Line 47 refers to the following code:

```
my $outputfilename = $file . "_FORMATTED" . $extention;
```

In the output folder, there is a file with the name "_FORMATTED" (no file extensions)

I have looked for a solution, and from my limited understanding I don't think the variables: file and extension are being defined, but I have no idea how to correct!

Comment: You need to call this program with a filename as the command line argument. There is a lot of error checking and the code is not bad, but there is no checking if that argument is there.

Comment: @user6731224 Check the line number 18. They are capturing the filename from command line so you should run the program `perl file.pl trackingdetail.csv`.  For trial hard code the input file name as `my $inputfile = "trackingdetail.csv"` and run the program.

Comment: I should have said that there is a "watcher" script monitoring a folder and this calls the program. I have edited the initial question with this code in addition.

Comment: If the argument is there, then it has to have the wrong format. There's this pattern match on `$inputfile` that grabs the right values for `$path`, `$file` and `$extension`. It probably does not match anything because the filenames have changed. Print out `$inputfile` directly after it is set to see what's going on.

Comment: You have *`$extension`* in the warnings you are showing, but the script has **`$extention`** ... Which one is it?

Comment: @SinanÜnür - my apologies, it is $extention

Comment: Copy & paste the actual code you are running (with no commented out lines), the actual output you are getting, and show how you run the program. Do this by editing and updating your question, not in the comments. If you are not willing to the tiniest amount of work composing a question, do not expect others to be able to give you quality help. If you are not willing to do that work, you may be better off paying someone to help you with this.

Comment: @user6731224: You say you have no experience of Perl, but are you a programmer in any language?

Comment: @SinanÜnür - Thank you for the feedback, I have amended the initial question which will hopefully be clearer.

Comment: @user6731224: `my $output = '\\\OUTPUT LOCATION';` In this output location you are using `\\\\` triple back slash hence could you please confirm this is sample or live.

Comment: @DaveCross - work with SQL but that's about it... was trying to get my head around this code so going forward could administer changes independantly.

Comment: @ssr1012 - no have now amended, the code uses double back slash, but on screen one was omitted so I added an additional one.

Comment: I'd guess your file name convention has changed recently? With `\\gen-svr-01\users\DATA\MW\DMO_Report_IO\INPUT/OrderTracking.csv` the pattern doesn't match and you get the _uninitialized..._ warning. But `\\gen-svr-01\users\DATA\MW\DMO_Report_IO\INPUT/Order1234Tracking.csv` (with 4 digits whithin the filename) gives `$path='\\gen-svr-01\users\DATA\MW\DMO_Report_IO\INPUT/', $file='Order1234', and $extention='.csv'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help to know which is line 47 in this code. I assume it's this line:

```
my $outputfilename = $file . "_FORMATTED" . $extention;
```

So, at this point, `$file` and `$extention` are both uninitialised. They are both supposed to be initialised in the previous line:

```
my ($path,$file,$extention) =
  $inputfile =~ m/ \A (.+\/) (.+\d\d\d\d) .+ ([.]\w{3}) \z/ixms;
```

So it seems that your `$inputfile` doesn't match the regex. This leaves us with two options:

1. `$inputfile` isn't being set at all (which would mean it isn't being passed to the program).
2. `$inputfile` isn't in the correct format to to match the regex.

To work out which of the problems we have here, add the following validation lines before the line which tries to set `$file` and `$extention`:

```
 die "No input file given\n" unless $inputfile;
 die "Input file name ($inputfile) is the wrong format\n"
   unless $inputfile =~ / \A (.+\/) (.+\d\d\d\d) .+ ([.]\w{3}) \z/ixms;
```

**Update:** From recent updates to your question, I can see that you are running the program and passing it the filename `\\gen-svr-01\users\DATA\MW\DMO_Report_IO\INPUT/OrderTracking.csv`.

Let's take a closer look at your regex.

```
m/ \A (.+\/) (.+\d\d\d\d) .+ ([.]\w{3}) \z/ixms
```

The `/x` option at the end means that the regex compiler ignores any literal whitespace in the string. So we can do the same. Let's break down what the individual parts are trying to match:

- `\A` : matches the start of the string
- `(.*\/)` : matches anything up to and including the last `/` in your string. It captures the matched substring into `$1`. This is what is stored in `$path` in your code. It's the directory that your file is in.
- `(.+\d\d\d\d)` : This matches one or more of any character followed by four digits. This is stored in `$2` and in your code it ends up in `$file``. It's the main part of the filename.
- `.+` : Matches one or more characters. Any characters. Your code does nothing with these characters.
- `([.]\w{3})` : Matches a dot followed by three "word" characters (basically alphanumerics). This is captured into `$3` and ends up in your `$extention` variable.
- `\z` : Matches the end of the string.

Putting all that together, you have a regex that looks for filenames and splits them into three parts - the path, the name and the extension. The only complication is that the filename section needs to contain four consecutive digits. And your filename is `OrderTracking` - which doesn't contain those required digits. So the regex doesn't match and your variables don't get set.

When this program was written, it was assumed that the filenames would contain four digits. The files that you are trying to process do not contain digits, so the program fails.

We can't suggest how you fix this. You need to speak to the people who supply your input files and find out why they have started to send you files with a different name format. Once you know that, you can decide one the best approach to work round the problems.

Comment: I have added the code and rerun the program. I am the error is as follows: Global symbol "$inputfilename" requires explicit package name <did you forget to declare "my $inputfilename"?> at c:\workspace\bin\WS_DMO_Report_Manipulation_V1.0.pl line 45 Global symbol "$inputfilename" requires explicit package name <did you forget to declare "my $inputfilename"?> at c:\workspace\bin\WS_DMO_Report_Manipulation_V1.0.pl line 46 Global symbol "$inputfilename" requires explicit package name <did you forget to declare "my $inputfilename"?> at c:\workspace\bin\WS_DMO_Report_Manipulation_V1.0.pl line 47

Comment: syntax error at c:\workspace\bin\WS_DMO_Report_Manipulation_V1.0.pl line 47, near r "/;"

Comment: Execution of c:\workspace\bin\WS_DMO_Report_Manipulation_V1.0.pl aborted due to compilation errors

Comment: @user6731224: Sorry, I made a mistake with that variable name (because your variables are named inconsistently). I've edited my answer to change `$inputfilename` to just `$inputfile`.

Comment: To be honest, I'd expect a programmer to be able to understand what that error message means and make the appropriate changes.

Comment: I have rerun - the watcher reports: "syntax error at c:\Workspace\bin\WS_DMO_Report_Manipulation_v1.0pl line 47 near "/;" - Line 47 in the code refers to:  unless $inputfile =~ / \A (.+\/) (.+\d\d\d\d) .+ ([.]\w{3}) \z/ixms/;

Comment: Sorry about some basic errors that must be frustrating - I really appreciate the patience and help.

Comment: @user6731224: Not sure where the spurious `/` at the end of that statement came from. I've removed it from the example. You should do the same. Sorry, I thought this was a simple cut-n-paste job, so I didn't bother checking that it even compiled. Won't make that mistake again :-/

Comment: @user6731224: Updated to explain exactly what is happening.

Comment: thanks for your help and explaining - will work through the input files now.